# Create bootstrap table with border radius

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm currently working with Bootstrap 5 and I have the following table

```css
.reasonCode-table {
  padding: 8px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

.reasonCode-table th {
  border: 2px solid #7a7878;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.reasonCode-table td {
  border: 2px solid #7a7878;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
   border-collapse: collapse;
}

.reasonCode-table__title {
  text-align: center;
}

.reasonCode-table__items {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.reasonCode-table__last-column {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="reasonCode-table rounded rounded-3 overflow-hidden">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-1 reasonCode-table__items">101</td>
      <td class="col-md-2 reasonCode-table__items">X764A</td>
      <td class="col-md-9 reasonCode-table__last-column">
        Claim submitted with incomplete patient information.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="reasonCode-table__items">202</td>
      <td class="reasonCode-table__items">H225B</td>
      <td class="reasonCode-table__last-column">
        The provided diagnosis code is invalid or not recognized.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="reasonCode-table__items">303</td>
      <td class="reasonCode-table__items">C879G</td>
      <td class="reasonCode-table__last-column">
        Procedure code billed is not covered under the patient's insurance plan.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="reasonCode-table__items">404</td>
      <td class="reasonCode-table__items">F512T</td>
      <td class="reasonCode-table__last-column">
        The claim contains duplicate service entries.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="reasonCode-table__items">505</td>
      <td class="reasonCode-table__items">Z989P</td>
      <td class="reasonCode-table__last-column">
        Billing provider is not authorized to perform the billed services.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I just want a normal table with `border-radius` of 6px, but when I try to do it, it is just not applying the borders when I use `border-collapse: collapse`, so first I tried to `set border-collapse: separate` and then apply the `collapse` to `td` and `th` elements, but the table still having separators, how can I create just a simple table with border-radius? And borders collapsable?

example of desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just set border collapse to none at .reasonCode-table. I tried it and i get your desired result.

Comment: If I do that, edges are barely visible